# How to handle UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in simple Mocha Unit Tests

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, mocha.js

simple mocha, nodejs unit test problem. I have a simple utilties class reading files from the local fs with fs-extra. The class is called FileUtils, takes a path and tries toi return the context by default ion utf-8. Simple:

```
async readFileContent(fqFileName, encoding='utf-8'){
        return fse.readFile(fqFileName,encoding)
            .then(content => content)
            .catch(any=>{
                throw any
            })
    }
```

My unit test simply requires the class FileUtils and invokes the method by calling

```
it.only('accepts an html template to compile', () => {
    let fixture = path.resolve(__dirname, '../_fixtures/100_tplWithDynamicBlocks.html')
    fileUtils.readFileContent(fixture)
        .then(content => {
            console.log(content) /* forget */
            content.should.not.be.null
        })
})
```

Working fine, everything is ok. But when I change the path to an invalid/non-existing-one, mocha is not getting aware of the error, only warning me, that unhandled promise rejections will exit the node processs in the future.

So my question is, how can I tell mocha that this test should be marked as failed without implementing any kind of catch signature, or better how should I implement the service method that mocha recognizes the missing file(or whatever) access.

Service implementation has to throw the error of a non-existing path (or any other error), but what is the best way to pass these errors to mocha without writing lines of unneccesary code mocha-framework is already doing?

Comment: ```
(node:13723) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Shared/devel/ais/ais-kernel-all/ais-kernel-cce-mailer/srv/test/unit/ais/ccm/_fixtures/100_tplWithDynamicBlocks.html'
(node:13723) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Wed, 04 Apr 2018 21:20:38 GMT mocha:runner finished running
```

Comment: Try adding a `.catch(err => console.log(error));` to the `fileUtils`'s `then` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the error with catch method after the then. Inside the method you can write the assert.